# List to Map of List using java streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a class Company

```
public class Company {

    private String companyid;

    private List<Employee> employees;
}
```

Which is related to Employee in One2Many relationship

```
public class Employee {

    private String employeeId;

    private Company company;

}
```

I am supplied with a list of employees and I want to generate a map like `Map<companyId, List<Employee>>` using java streams as it has to be performant.

```
employees.stream().collect(
                  Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getCompany, HashMap::new, Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

But the problem is I can't call something like Employee::getCompany().getCompanyId()

How can I do this. Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a lambda expression instead of a method reference:

```
Map<String,List<Employee> output =
    employees.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getCompany().getCompanyId(), 
                                            HashMap::new, 
                                            Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)));
```

Or simply:

```
Map<String,List<Employee> output =
    employees.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getCompany().getCompanyId()));
```

Comment: Hi, this line "e -> e.getCompany().getCompanyId()" is causing a compilation problem in java8. I can only use java8

Comment: @ds2799 this should work in Java8, assuming your `Employee` class has a `getCompany()` method that returns a `Company` and your `Company` class has a `getCompanyId()` method that returns a `String`.

Comment: Thanks it is working :)

Comment: Hi again, just one thing though it is throwing a NPE with just one item in the list and beans are completely filled.

Comment: @ds2799 this means either the input List contains a null value, or it contains an Employee having a null Company, or a Company having a null CompanyId. You can filter out the null values.

Comment: You were right, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
Map<String,List<Employee>> output =
    employees.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getCompany().getCompanyId(), HashMap::new, Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)));
```

Comment: I am getting a  NullPointerException. With just one item in the list and nothing is null.